# Simplifying a SQL Query with multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was wondering if you guys could help me simplifying the queries below in a **single query**.

I have 10 queries just like the one below. The only difference between all of them is field "Outcoming Task" which starts with 1 and goes until 10.

```
SELECT 
S1.[Main Project] AS Company, 
S1.[Main Link] AS Project, 
S1.[Name] AS Milestone, 
S1.[Start] AS MilestoneDueDate, 
S2.[Name] AS Successor, 
S2.[Start] AS SuccessorDueDate

FROM Sheet1 AS S1 INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S2 ON S1.[Outcoming Task 1] = S2.[ID]

WHERE 
S1.Start >S2.[Start] AND 
S1.[%compl#] <> 100 AND 
(S1.[Task class] <> '***Sammelvorgang' AND S1.[Task class] <> '' AND  S1.[Task class] <> 'M D-Muster') AND 
(S2.[Task class] <> '***Sammelvorgang' AND S2.[Task class] <> '' AND  S2.[Task class] <> 'M D-Muster')

ORDER BY 
S1.[Main Project], 
S1.[Main Link], 
S1.[Name];
```

The reason I created it is because the DBA instead of creating a table for the connections between tasks, has created 10 fields like Outcoming Task 1, Outcoming Task 2 and Outcoming Task 3...

Would it be possible to combine all queries in a single one?
Could you guys give me a tip on how to?

INFO:
MS-ACCESS 2010

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the query below. I also think, that spaces in a column name is not really best practice.

```
SELECT 
    S1.[Main Project] AS Company, 
    S1.[Main Link] AS Project, 
    S1.[Name] AS Milestone, 
    S1.[Start] AS MilestoneDueDate, 
    S2.[Name] AS Successor_Task1, 
    S2.[Start] AS SuccessorDueDate_Task1,

    S3.[Name] AS Successor_Task2, 
    S3.[Start] AS SuccessorDueDate_Task2,   

    ... 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ...

FROM 
    Sheet1 AS S1 
    LEFT JOIN Sheet1 AS S2 
        ON S1.[Outcoming Task 1] = S2.[ID]

    LEFT JOIN Sheet1 AS S3
        ON S1.[Outcoming Task 2] = S3.[ID]

    ... 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ...

WHERE 
    S1.Start >S2.[Start] AND 
    S1.[%compl#] <> 100 AND 
    (S1.[Task class] <> '***Sammelvorgang' AND S1.[Task class] <> '' AND  S1.[Task class] <> 'M D-Muster') AND 
    (S2.[Task class] <> '***Sammelvorgang' AND S2.[Task class] <> '' AND  S2.[Task class] <> 'M D-Muster') AND

    (S3.[Task class] <> '***Sammelvorgang' AND S3.[Task class] <> '' AND  S3.[Task class] <> 'M D-Muster')

    ... 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ...

ORDER BY 
    S1.[Main Project], 
    S1.[Main Link], 
    S1.[Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps you want a UNION query. Here's a simple example:

Say you have two tables

**[Table1]**
[ID] AutoNumber
[Outcoming Task 1] Numeric(Long Integer)
[Outcoming Task 2] Numeric(Long Integer)

with data

```
ID  Outcoming Task 1  Outcoming Task 2  
--  ----------------  ----------------  
1   1                 2  
2   1                 3
```

**[Tasks]**
[ID] AutoNumber
[TaskName] Text(255)

with data

```
ID  TaskName
--  --------
1   Task1
2   Task2
3   Task3
```

The query

```
SELECT t1.[ID], 1 AS [Outcoming Task], t.[TaskName]
FROM [Table1] t1 INNER JOIN [Tasks] t ON t.[ID] = t1.[Outcoming Task 1]
UNION
SELECT t1.[ID], 2 AS [Outcoming Task], t.[TaskName]
FROM [Table1] t1 INNER JOIN [Tasks] t ON t.[ID] = t1.[Outcoming Task 2]
```

will produce

```
ID  Outcoming Task  TaskName
--  --------------  --------
1   1               Task1
1   2               Task2
2   1               Task1
2   2               Task3
```